# Mod rewrite tags

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

my URL is like this.
http://site.org/index.php?page=tags&tag=tagname

I'd like to rewrite it to

http://site.com/tags/tagname

My current .htaccess

## RewriteEngine On

```
    # RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)$ $1.php [L]

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)$ index.php?paste=$1 [L]

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/edit$ index.php?paste=$1&page=edit [L]

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+).txt$ index.php?paste=$1&paste_txt=$1 [L]

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+).txt$ index.php?paste=$1&paste_txt=$1 [L]

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/delete$ index.php?paste=$1&page=delete [L]

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+).download$ index.php?paste=$1&paste_download=$1 [L]

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ([^/\.]+)/?.cgi$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

    #RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteRule ([^/\.]+)/?.txt$ index.php?paste_txt=$1 [L]

    #RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteRule ([^/\.]+)/?.download$ index.php?paste_download=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/?([A-za-z0-9]+)/([A-za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1&tag=$2 [L]
```

I believe this should do it... That is if you want numbers in your tags. If not, remove the 0-9 from each part of it.

Comment: Hell yeah buddy, worked. Thank you; played around with it for some time, I couldn't get it. I'm not too good with mod_rewrite.

Comment: What could I do to allow spaces?

Comment: Give the answer a vote up so it might help someone searching for it in the future :)

Comment: Can't not enough reputation :/ what could I alter to allow spaces?

Comment: Do not put spaces in your URL. :P